# Why isn’t a source/byte code file imported as a module when run as a script?

Tags: python, module, python-import, program-entry-point

From the Python documentation of the [import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#special-considerations-for-main) (bold emphasis mine):

> ## 5.8. Special considerations for `__main__`
>
> The `__main__` module is a special case relative to Python’s import system. As noted elsewhere,
> the `__main__` module is directly initialized at interpreter startup,
> much like `sys` and `builtins`. However, unlike those two, it doesn’t
> strictly qualify as a built-in module. This is because the manner in
> which `__main__` is initialized depends on the flags and other options
> with which the interpreter is invoked.
>
> ### 5.8.1. `__main__.__spec__`
>
> Depending on how `__main__` is initialized, `__main__.__spec__` gets set appropriately or to `None`.
>
> When Python is started with the `-m` option, `__spec__` is set to the
> module spec of the corresponding module or package. `__spec__` is also
> populated when the `__main__` module is loaded as part of executing a
> directory, zipfile or other `sys.path` entry.
>
> In the remaining cases `__main__.__spec__` is set to `None`, as the code
> used to populate the `__main__` does not correspond directly with an
> importable module:
>
> - interactive prompt
> - `-c` option
> - running from stdin
> - running directly from a source or bytecode file
>
> **Note that `__main__.__spec__` is always `None` in the last
> case, *even if* the file could technically be imported directly as a
> module instead.** Use the `-m` switch if valid module metadata is desired
> in `__main__`.
>
> Note also that even when `__main__` corresponds with an importable
> module and `__main__.__spec__` is set accordingly, they’re still
> considered *distinct* modules. This is due to the fact that blocks
> guarded by `if __name__ == "__main__":` checks only execute when the
> module is used to populate the `__main__` namespace, and not during
> normal import.

Why isn’t a source/byte code file imported as a module when run as a script?

Comment: Because none of the conditions that set it to something else apply.

Comment: @Barmar Why is it not considered an importable module even if it could? What is the motivation behind that exception?

Comment: It may be importable, but you're not actually importing it.

Comment: @Barmar But you are neither importing the module when initializing the module from `-m` or from a directory, zipfile or other `sys.path` entry, are you? Yet in these cases the module is considered importable.

Comment: The `-m` option specifically means to treat it as a module.

Comment: @Barmar It seems that `__spec__ is None` when there is no package context, i.e. when `__package__ is None` (but not when `__package__ == ''` like with `-m` for top-level modules or with a `sys.path` entry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in the documentation, a source/byte code file is not imported as a module when run *as a script* (`python <file path>`) because running the code *as a module* is already the purpose of the `-m` argument (`python -m <module name>`).